# Upload file in WebService just one time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webforms

I need to upload a file from an asp.net webform application through WebService (.asmx) that I transform to bytes and save to a database.

**But** the problem is that the file is always uploaded two times which creates a duplicate in my database table. When I start the debug mode, the break point moves up as if I had clicked the start upload button twice.

I use this library [Simple example of ajax file upload](http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery) and I would be grateful if you would have the answer to this technical problem. I've searched for many hours but I have found nothing yet.

**Edit**
To answer to Garrison Neely: The code when the page load is

```
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        this.ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsyncPostBackTimeout"]);
        this.ParentRepeaterBind();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

And the code on upload button is :

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        if (Context.Request.Files[0] != null && Context.Request.Files[0].InputStream != null)
        {
            bytes = ReadStream(Context.Request.Files[0].InputStream);

            // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
            string filePath = Context.Request.Files[0].FileName;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string contenttype = String.Empty;

            //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".doc":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".docx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype = "image/jpg";
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    contenttype = "image/png";
                    break;
                case ".gif":
                    contenttype = "image/gif";
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    contenttype = "application/pdf";
                    break;
            }
            if (contenttype != String.Empty)
            {
                Stream fs = Context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                //insert the file into database
                string strQuery = "insert into dbo.FileUpload(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
                InsertUpdateData(cmd);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the C# code that you are using when the page loads and the button to upload is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

A solution besides trying to figure out, why are the async post back being made twice is to save the file md5 checksum.

In your database, create an extra column called checksum and save the MD5(data), then, when saving files in your database, perform a previous check whether a file with the same checksum already exists.

This prevents your table from holding repeated files, that would have been uploaded anyway, by different users for example.

You can compute your hash with this code:

```
MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
byte[] hash = md5Hash.ComputeHash(bytes);
string checksum = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Insert checksum in your database, and use it to perform previous file existence check.

Regards.